# PHP execution function when assigned to a variable

Tags: php, function, variable-assignment

I have a function that 'echos' before returning an array. When assigning that function to a variable like below, it executes the function outputting the echo. Is this expected behavior as I thought assigning to a variable should only do just that, assign? Thanks

```
 function check($link) {
 //.....
  echo "some text ";
 return $array;

}

 $test = check($link);
```

Comment: Yes it is normal, it echos AND assigns the value to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a function to a variable like that what php is actually doing is executing the function to get its return value and then assigning that value to the variable.

So php executes your function (and therefore does the echo statement) and then assigns the return value ($array) to $test.

Answer (score 0):

it executes line by line so when it gets `echo "some text ";` it prints and after that it returns the array.

Comment: So by assigning I am also calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is expected behavior. You are creating a side effect(echoing) while also assigning to a variable. You are doing what is called a query and a command in the same time, which is totally legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

PHP interpreter will execute anything within your function. The `echo` function is the equivalent of `System.out.print` in Java, `Console.WriteLine` in C# and `cout` in C++. It's like writing out a sequence of text to a standard output. The only difference here would be that instead of a console you have the client's Web browser, so the mentioned character sequence is sent back to browser within the HTTP response body.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

In PHP, as weird, as may look, it does that.

But, as a programming design, it strongly recommended to separate display from programming logic:

```
/* array */ function check($link) {
  /* array */ $Result = array();

  //...

  $Result[] = "Sun";

  //...

  $Result[] = "Mercury";
  $Result[] = "Venus";
  $Result[] = "Earth";

  //...

  return $Result;
}

/* array */ $test = check($link);
```

But, sometimes, printing directly to browser console, may be helpul, for debugging:

```
/* array */ function check($link) {
  /* array */ $Result = array();

  //...

  // uncomment, just in severe cases
  //echo("link: [" . $link . "]");

  //...

  $Result[] = "Sun";

  //...

  $Result[] = "Mercury";
  $Result[] = "Venus";
  $Result[] = "Earth";

  //...

  return $Result;
}

/* array */ $test = check($link);
```

just my 2 cents, Cheers.